# Access the application context inside of a singleton

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a singleton that I'm using to open a JSON asset and return it as a list.  I need to access the application context in order to use the Asset Manager.  I can't pass in the context because I'm calling it from a view model, which does not have access to the application context.  I've done a lot of searching but I can't seem to find the answer.

```
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter
import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi
import com.squareup.moshi.Types
import com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory

object ProgramListService {
    fun getProgramList(): List<ProgramList>? {

        val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()
        
        val json = context.assets.open("programs/home.json").bufferedReader().use{ it.readText() }
        val listType = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, ProgramList::class.java)
        val adapter: JsonAdapter<List<ProgramList>> = moshi.adapter(listType)

        return adapter.fromJson(json)
    }
}
```

Comment: ViewModel certainly can have access to application context, use `AndroidViewModel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context is not good in a ViewModel, not even application context, nor is AndroidViewModel good to use. So you can pass AssetManager into your ViewModel which can then pass it into your ProgramListService, avoiding the need for context, but asset manager is still a bit weird to have in view model.

So you can skip the viewmodel and pass the application context directly into your singleton ProgramListService.

```
object ProgramListService {
    lateinit var application: Application // Add this

    ...
}
```

And then from your activity's onCreate or wherever is best for your project,

```
ProgramListService.application = context.applicationContext as Application
```

Or like @Tenfour04 suggested application is safe to make a global property

Comment: I am marking this one as the answer because: 1. It avoids passing the context to the ViewModel and 2. It avoids creating a global variable. Coming from a JavaScript background I avoid global variables whenever possible, though I really don't know if that idea has any relation to Kotlin and Java.  Thanks!

Comment: P.S. I added ```ProgramListService.application = context.applicationContext as Application``` to the fragment that I'm calling ```getProgramList()``` from.  I also changed ```context.assets``` to ```application.assets```

Answer (score 0):

You have the Context in ViewModel

```
public class HomeViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

public HomeViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);

    Context context = getApplication().getApplicationContext();

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would hesitate to call what you have a singleton, since it doesn't carry any state. You've used an `object` to organize the namespace of what would be a static method in Java.

If your ViewModel is an AndroidViewModel, it comes with an `Application` instance, so you can use that as your context:

```
class MyViewModel(val application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    fun foo() {
        someRepoAccessCall(application)
    }
}
```

Since the Application is safe to use as a singleton, you can alternatively create a global property for it that you initially set in `onCreate()`.

```
lateinit var application: MyApplication

class MyApplication(): Application
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        application = this
    }
}
```

Don't forget to assign the custom Application class in the manifest:

```xml
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        ...
```